# python polling wait for return value

Tags: python, polling

I want to poll the return value of a function:

```
def myfunction():
   df=df_function()
   global value
   value=df[df['date']==date]
   return True

polling2.poll(
   lambda: myfunction == True,
   step=30,
   timeout=3600)
```

But does not work: the polling script runs indefinitely.

Comment: `lambda: myfunction() == True` you forgot to call your function

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, but I had an issue with the function() on a previous test.
Perfect, thanks!